# Pronunciation of the big-O notation

Tags: pronunciation, mathematics

How should I pronounce the following things? (These are complexities of algorithms.)

> - O(n)
> - O(n*log(n))
> - O(n^2)

Comment: This question is more appropriate for math.stackexchange.com or cstheory.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Mitch *cstheory* is for research level questions only, see http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: I think this is a pointless question. Does OP really want to know whether **O** is pronounced as **Owe** rather than **Big Oh**? Or maybe it should be pronounced **zer-OWE**? I'm voting to close, and if I could delete it I would do that.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Pronunciation would be:

- order n
- order n log n
- order n squared

Comment: If the context (of computational order) is already established, I've also heard "o of n" (etc).

Comment: Its just known as the 'Big O' in my discrete math class. aka the maximum amount of times an algorithm will be run.

Answer (score 17):

In the talks I've seen that involve algorithm complexity, I've heard it most often pronounced "oh of n", "oh of n log n", etc.

Mathematicians and CS theorists also use a lowercase *o* and a capital ϴ for similar measurements with slightly different implications.  In this case *O*( *n* ) would be pronounced "big oh of n", *o*( *n* ) "little oh of n", and ϴ(*n*) "theta of n".

Comment: A footnote on the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) says *O(g(n))* is *pronounced "big-oh of g of n" or sometimes just "oh of g of n"*, referencing Cormen, Thomas H.; Leiserson, Charles E.; Rivest, Ronald L. (2009). Introduction to Algorithms (3rd ed.). Cambridge/MA: MIT Press. p. 47.

Comment: @StuartF: Thanks for adding the reference!

Answer (score 6):

That is commonly referred to as [Big O Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), and since my days as a math/CS student I have always pronounced it (and heard it pronounced) as "Big O of n", "Big O of n log n", etc.

Comment: [Oh oh oh, the big big O, Overstock.com...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FutfNko9EE4)

Answer (score 3):

I think it's also common to just say "oh" followed by whatever is inside the parentheses.

Examples:

> There is an "oh n log n" algorithm for that problem
>
> Doesn't that require "oh n squared" time in the worst case?

Answer (score -1):

The ‚Θ -notation asymptotically bounds a function from above and below. When
we have only an asymptotic upper bound, we use O-notation. For a given function
g(n), we denote by O(g(n)) (pronounced “big-oh of g of n” or sometimes
just “oh of g of n”) the set of functions

O(g(n)) = { f(n): there exist positive constants c and n0 such that
0 ≤ f(n) ≤ c.g(n) for all n ≥ n<sub>0</sub>}

ref: *Introduction to Algorithms*, fourth edition

Comment: This was probably unneeded.  It does not tell us anything new about the question ("pronunciation"); and furthermore it has been more than 10 years.